# Is it possible to use named parameters when command type is adCmdText?

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, vbscript, ado, named-parameters

I'm trying to use named parameters with following query through Adodb.Command but no luck.

```sql
Select * From mytable Where col1 = Lower(@param1) And col2 = Upper(@param2) And col3 = @param1
```

The code I used something like that.

```vb
Dim cmd
Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("Adodb.Command")
cmd.NamedParameters = True
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
cmd.CommandText = "Select * From mytable Where col1 = Lower(@param1) And col2 = Upper(@param2) And col3 = @param1"
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@param1", adVarchar, adParamInput, 20, "some text 1")
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@param2", adVarchar, adParamInput, 20, "some text 2")
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
Dim rs
Set rs = cmd.Execute
```

The problem is that, this causes an error on RDBMS side.

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80040e14'
>
> Must declare the scalar variable "@param1".

There's no any trouble if the query is a stored procedure call. So, I guess **[namedparameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/namedparameters-property-ado)** affects for only command objects which calls stored procedures.
When I track the query using SQL Server Profiler, I saw just the following queries ran *(note that, no parameter declaration, no value assignment)*.

```
SQL:BatchStarting   Select * From mytable Where col1 = Lower(@param1) And col2 = Upper(@param2)
SQL:BatchCompleted  Select * From mytable Where col1 = Lower(@param1) And col2 = Upper(@param2)
```

However I need to do it on native vary queries. How can I do it, what is the best practice doing that without string concatenation etc. I don't want to prepare queries with question marks, and I don't like passing parameters with order (it's necessary with question marks and without named parameters) and multiple times. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update on misunderstandings:** I am looking for a general solution that is not depending on the database.

Answer (score 10):

You can't use named parameters with ad-hoc queries in OLE DB.  If you're using SQL Server, you could do something like this:

```vb
Dim sql
sql = ""
sql = sql & "DECLARE @param1 varchar(20) = ?;"
sql = sql & "DECLARE @param2 varchar(20) = ?;"
sql = sql & "Select * From mytable Where col1 = Lower(@param1) And col2 = Upper(@param2) And col3 = @param1;"

' This section is basically the same as in the original question
Dim cmd
Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("Adodb.Command")
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
cmd.CommandText = sql
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@param1", adVarchar, adParamInput, 20, "some text 1")
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@param2", adVarchar, adParamInput, 20, "some text 2")
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
Dim rs
Set rs = cmd.Execute
```

You still have to bind the parameters positionally, but this way, the correct order is easier to see and you can use the same parameter in multiple locations.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm late to return. First, thank you very match. The trick you gave is cleverly. But it's not enough for me. I just want to make it easier but this is not easy as I expected. Let me explain the last state. I'm on MySQL Server. However MySQL ODBC drivers does not support declarations in command scope like you shown, need to declare through connection object as session variables. Therefore, wait for a better solution. If not, this is the acceptable answer already. Good luck.

Comment: @remiremi, your question explicitly mentions SQL Server in multiple places. If you now need an answer for MySQL, I'd suggest asking a new question.

Comment: It was the test case because of SQL Server's Profiler feature. My question is related `ADO` totally. I'm looking for a general solution because the application I'm developing current should be compatible with four (sql server, mysql, sqlite, ms access) different database type. So I'm afraid I'll not ask a new question.