# ADO parameterised query not returning any result

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, asp-classic, ado, named-parameters

I am using this query to get some results from my vbscript in a classic asp page and It does not come back with any values. The page is blank and there are no errors too. Any suggestion please?

```vb
dim cmd, admin_no
admin_no = request.QueryString("admin")

set cmd = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmd.ActiveConnection = con
sql = ""
sql = sql & "DECLARE @admin_no int;"
sql = sql & "SELECT field1, field2 FROM mydb.mytable where admin_no = @admin_no"
cmd.CommandText = sql
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@admin_no", adInteger, adParamInput, , admin_no)

'response.write(cmd.Parameters(0))
'response.write(cmd.CommandText)

set rs = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset") 
rs.Open cmd
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem here is `adCmdText` uses `?` placeholder for passing parameters, change the line

```
sql = sql & "SELECT field1, field2 FROM mydb.mytable where admin_no = @admin_no"
```

to

```
sql = sql & "SELECT field1, field2 FROM mydb.mytable where admin_no = ?"
```

---

If [you are wanting to pass named parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36154160/ado-parameterised-query-not-returning-any-result#comment59947287_36154194) to your query you don't have too many options but this little trick is useful.

```
sql = ""
sql = sql & "DECLARE @admin_no int;"
sql = sql & "SET @admin_no = ?;"
sql = sql & "SELECT field1, field2 FROM mydb.mytable where admin_no = @admin_no"
```

---

#### Useful Links

- [Using Stored Procedure in Classical ASP .. execute and get results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20702205/692942)
- [ASP parameters to call a stored procedure in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24010555/692942)
- [Change stored proc to inline sql](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36127333/692942)

Comment: Cheers @Lankymart , It seems to work, but I acutally wanted to pass parameter names in the Sql statment so that its more readable, how do I achieve this? when I say parameter names, I mean in the above sql, I say ...where admin_no=@admin_no instead of admin_no=?

Comment: @Pravi I'm fairly sure you can't, ADO doesn't support it.

Comment: @Pravi See [Is it possible to use named parameters when command type is adCmdText?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11788727/692942). I demonstrate the workaround described there in [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36127333/692942).

Comment: I will assume there are some rules to it, fieldname should match the name of the createParameter function, am I correct??

Comment: @Pravi There is a lot of information in those links at the end of my answer. But basically unless using `Refresh()` method with `NamedParameters = True` you have to specifiy / append the parameters in order they appear in the SQL.

Comment: If I go with the example shown by Cheran ie  Is it possible to use named parameters when command type is adCmdText? I get                   Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80040e14' 
Cannot assign a default value to a local variable.

Comment: @Pravi That sounds more like a SQL Server error then an Classic ASP one, make sure the syntax you are using is correct. Should be `DECLARE @admin_no AS INT` then `SET @admin_no = ?` then in the rest of the SQL you can use `@admin_no` where needed.

Comment: @Pravi  Have provided a quick example in [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36154194/692942).

Comment: If you are really wanting to name your parameters like you suggest why not move this to a stored proc? You have all the naming clarity you are looking for and you have taken a step towards separating the data layer and business layer. It would be a win-win.

Comment: thank you guys, @Lankymart, you answered my question and Sean Lange, will look into your suggestion. Cheers