# SQL parameters not returning any results

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, parameters, asp-classic, adodb

Following code is not returning any results:

```vb
search = "'%" & Request.QueryString("itemname") & "%'"

Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.COMMAND")  
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = conn

sql = ""
sql = sql & "DECLARE @search varchar;"
sql = sql & "SET @search = ?;"

sql = sql & "SELECT ID, itemname, itemtype FROM vw_items WHERE itemname LIKE @search"

    cmd.CommandText = sql
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdText

response.write("<strong>You searched for:</strong> " & search & "<br /><br 
/>")    

cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@search", adVarchar, adParamInput, 50, search)

set rs = cmd.Execute
else

    search = null
    strSQL2 =   "SELECT * FROM vw_items"
    set rs = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rs.open strSQL2,conn

end if
```

I've seen this answer: [ADO parameterised query not returning any result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36154160/ado-parameterised-query-not-returning-any-result) and tried fixing mine but no luck

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Because you use a parameterised query the type is inferred when you create the parameter so there is no need for the single quotes *(`'`)* around the `search` variable in essence at the moment when the `ADODB.Command` is executed it is doing `WHERE itemname LIKE ''%youritemname%''`  when you actually want it to be `WHERE itemname LIKE '%youritemname%'`. Change the `search` variable to `search = "%" & Request.QueryString("itemname") & "%"` to fix it.

Comment: Are you sure you using MySQL as this looks an awful lot like MS SQL Server T-SQL?

Comment: is this "search " has a return value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `ADODB.Command` the provider infers the data type based off the `Parameters` collection that is setup before calling the `Execute()` method.

As you are passing in as

```vb
search = "'%" & Request.QueryString("itemname") & "%'"
```

in effect when the SQL is executed by the provider it will look like *(because it already knows the `Parameter` is a `VARCHAR` data type already)*

```sql
WHERE itemname LIKE ''%youritemname%''
```

When you actually want it to be

```sql
WHERE itemname LIKE '%youritemname%'
```

This means the current query is doing a `LIKE` for the physical string `'%youritemname%'` rather than doing an actually pattern matching query.

The fix is simple, remove the single quotes from the `search` variable, like so;

```vb
search = "%" & Request.QueryString("itemname") & "%"
```

---

#### Useful Links

- [A: How to use ASP variables in SQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20702205/692942) *(useful tips when working with the `ADODB.Command` object)*